# Google visualization dashboards - how to get the new set of data after filtering

Tags: dashboard, google-visualization

I'm creating a google visualization dashboard with multiple filters, sliders, a table and a column chart. The table has duplicate rows in the status column (column 0), so I have a view calc logic to get the count of each status. All this works fine. In order to hide the rows that I don't want to see (basically duplicates), I am using view.rows and passing in an array of the row numbers that I want to display.

When I first load the HTML, everything works fine. If I  use the Order priority level slider (rangeSlider) and slide the max value to 4 from 5, my table changes accordingly, and now I have only 5 rows of data and not 6. at this point, the view.rows is still looking at the original 6 rows, and I get an error saying 'Invalid Row index 5. Should be in the range [0-4]'.

If I don't have the view.rows array, it works fine, but my column chart shows all duplicate rows as well.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!!

### Here is my code:

```
<html><head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls']});

var rows = 0;
function drawDashboard() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Status','Priority','Order No.','Description','Func. Loc.','Type','Start Dt','Fin Date'],
    ['RSCH',2,500400,'Hard disk problem (SAP01)','1171-ADMI-0001 ','SM01',new Date(2005, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 0, 2)],
    ['INIT',1,501300,'','','SM02',new Date(2007, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 11, 2)],
    ['RSCH',1,500400,'Hard disk problem (SAP01)','1171-ADMI-0001 ','SM01',new Date(2005, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 0, 2)],
    ['INIT',2,501300,'','','SM02',new Date(2007, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 11, 2)],
    ['RSCH',5,500400,'Hard disk problem (SAP01)','1171-ADMI-0001 ','SM01',new Date(2005, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 0, 2)],
    ['RDSP',4,501300,'','','SM02',new Date(2007, 0, 1),new Date(2009, 11, 2)]
]);


// Create a dashboard.
 dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
 document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
// Create a range slider, passing some options
 var rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter','containerId': 'slider_div',
    'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Priority','ui': {'label':'Order Priority Level:'}}});
// Create a range slider, passing some options
 var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter','containerId': 'dateSlider_div',
    'options': {'filterColumnLabel':'Start Dt','ui': {'label':'Start Date :'}}});
// Create a range slider, passing some options
 var dateRangeSliderFin = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter','containerId': 'dateSliderFin_div',
    'options': {'filterColumnLabel':'Fin Date','ui': {'label':'Finish Date:'}}});
// Define category filters
var FlocFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
     'controlType': 'CategoryFilter', 'containerId': 'FLfilter_div',
     'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Func. Loc.','ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical','allowTyping': false,'allowMultiple': false}}});
var StatFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
     'controlType': 'CategoryFilter', 'containerId': 'Statfilter_div',
     'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Status','ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical','allowTyping': true,'allowMultiple': true}}});
var TypeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
     'controlType': 'CategoryFilter', 'containerId': 'Typefilter_div',
     'options': {'filterColumnLabel': 'Type','ui': { 'labelStacking': 'vertical','allowTyping': true,'allowMultiple': true}}});


// Define a table
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    dataTable:data,
    containerId: 'table_div',
    options: {'width': '800px'}
});

    rows = data.getNumberOfRows();
    distinct_values = data.getDistinctValues(0);

    arRows = [];
    for (var ii=0; ii<distinct_values.length; ii++){
        for (var jj=0; jj<rows; jj++){
            var curr_stat = data.getValue(jj,0);
            if (curr_stat == distinct_values[ii]){
                arRows.push(jj);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

// Draw a column chart
var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    options: {'title': 'Status vs. Order Count'},
    containerId: 'columnChart_div',
    view: {'columns': [0,{calc:testfunc, type:'number', label:'Count..'}],'rows':arRows}
});



function testfunc(dataTable, rowNum){   
    var curr_stat = dataTable.getValue(rowNum,0);
    var distinct_values = dataTable.getDistinctValues(0);
    var count = 0;

    for (var ii=0; ii<dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); ii++){
        stat = dataTable.getValue(ii,0);
        if (stat == curr_stat){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}




// Establish dependencies
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider,dateRangeSlider);
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider,dateRangeSliderFin);
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider,FlocFilter);
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider,StatFilter);
dashboard.bind(rangeSlider,TypeFilter);

dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider,dateRangeSliderFin);
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider,FlocFilter);
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider,StatFilter);
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSlider,TypeFilter);

dashboard.bind(dateRangeSliderFin,FlocFilter);
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSliderFin,StatFilter);
dashboard.bind(dateRangeSliderFin,TypeFilter);

dashboard.bind(FlocFilter,StatFilter);
dashboard.bind(FlocFilter,TypeFilter);

dashboard.bind(StatFilter,TypeFilter);

dashboard.bind([rangeSlider,dateRangeSlider,dateRangeSliderFin,FlocFilter,StatFilter,TypeFilter],[table,columnChart]);

// Draw the dashboard.  
dashboard.draw(data);

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

</script></head>
<body style='font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;'>
<div id='dashboard_div'>
<h3>PM Work Orders</h3>
<table>
     <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
        <td style='width: 600px; font-size: 0.8em;'>
            <div id='slider_div' style='width:500px;'></div></br></br>
            <div id='dateSlider_div' style='width:500px;'></div></br></br>
            <div id='dateSliderFin_div' style='width:500px;'></div></br></br></br>
            <div id='columnChart_div' style='width:500px;'></div></br></br>
        </td>   
        <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.8em;'>
            <div id='FLfilter_div' style='width:300px;'></div></br>
            <div id='Statfilter_div' style='width:300px;'></div></br>
            <div id='Typefilter_div' style='width:300px;'></div></br>
        </td>
        <td style='width: 1500px'>
             <div id='table_div'></div>

         </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can vastly simplify your controls by chaining them, which will make the rest of this a bit easier as well.  Replace your `dashboard.bind` calls with these:

```
dashboard.bind([rangeSlider], [dateRangeSlider]);
dashboard.bind([dateRangeSlider], [dateRangeSliderFin]);
dashboard.bind([dateRangeSliderFin], [FlocFilter]);
dashboard.bind([FlocFilter], [StatFilter]);
dashboard.bind([StatFilter], [TypeFilter]);
dashboard.bind([TypeFilter], [table, columnChart]);
```

Then move your code that calculates `arRows` to a function (with a few small modifications):

```
function setChartRows () {
    var dt = columnChart.getDataTable();
    var rows = dt.getNumberOfRows();
    var distinct_values = dt.getDistinctValues(0);

    var arRows = [];
    for (var ii=0; ii<distinct_values.length; ii++){
        for (var jj=0; jj<rows; jj++){
            var curr_stat = dt.getValue(jj,0);
            if (curr_stat == distinct_values[ii]){
                arRows.push(jj);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    var view = columnChart.getView();
    view.rows = arRows;
    columnChart.setView(view);
    columnChart.draw();
}
```

Then set up an event handler for the Table's `'ready'` event

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', setChartRows);
```

Every time the table gets updated, the chart will re-calculate it's rows and redraw with the new rows set.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/bLQ2D/

Comment: I can get it to work by showing all rows of the table as columns (and not just the distinct ones), or I can get the distinct ones to show up with the initial state before I do any filtering.....

Comment: There were two problems: first, you need to remove the `"rows":arRows` bit from the chart's `view` parameter.  Second, I was missing an "s" at the end of "events" in the event handler.  I updated my answer with the fix and a link to a jsfiddle showing it working.